# Склоняется ли омега-3, омега-9?

Tags: склонение

Правильно ли будет написать так: *Содержание омеги-3 – 75 %?*

Видела единственный ответ "Грамоты.ру" на эту тему:
*"Этот термин склоняется, если он употреблен без родового слова".*

Есть ли еще какие-то источники?

Comment: Тогда склоняйте. На мой взгляд, это, скорее, разговорный, нежели книжный язык.

Answer (score 3):

**Вопрос № 263950**

Подскажите, пожалуйста (если можно, срочно), **склоняется** ли термин "омега-3". Наш рекламный отдел утверждает, что правильно "омегой-3, омеге-3".

Ответ справочной службы русского языка. Этот термин **склоняется**, если он употреблен без родового слова.

Однако на практике мы видим **несклоняемый вариант** без родового слова, что представляется весьма разумным. Падежные формы слова по образцу 1-го склонения выглядят странно: омеге-3, омегу-3. Можно сказать, что общая **тенденция** – не склонять название для сохранения его **точности.**

Тогда запишем так: **содержание омега-3 – 75 %**

https://norwegianfishoil.ru/blog/stati-i-publikacii/kak-pravilno-pit-omega-3-glavnye-pravila/

[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Омега-3-ненасыщенные_жирные_кислоты](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0-3-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8B%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B)

Answer (score 1):

Если сомневаетесь, добавьте родовое слово, и всё сразу встанет на свои места:

*И.п.*: "Омега-3-кислот**ы** необходимы для развития мозга".

*Р.п.*: "Содержание омега-3-кислот в этом БАДе достигает 75%".

Comment: К сожалению, добавлять мне ничего нельзя :(